# Graphics, UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range

Tags: ios, image, graphics

I got Xcode 8 and a folder with images. I have replaced all images with specific filters in Photoshop, Pixalate.

When I run my project, I get an error:

> [Graphics] UIColor created with component values far outside the expected range, Set a breakpoint on UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents to debug. This message will only be logged once.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 76):

You might have something like this somewhere :

```
UIColor(red: 255, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
```

need to be changed like this now :

```
UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
SO : UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Comment: I have UIColor(red: 70/255, green: 40/255, blue: 17/255, alpha: 1.0) , so how to edit??

Comment: Thanks for ur ans, I set wrong code like this : [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0];

Answer (score 60):

As mentioned in your warning info, you just set the value outside the expected range. According to the API Reference, every parameter pass to UIColor generator should be between 0.0 and 1.0.

You can follow the steps bellow to find out the code which cause this warning:

Step 1: add a Symbolic Breakpoint in your breakpoint navigator
[image: add a Symbolic Breakpoint]

Step 2: set the symbol of the Symbolic Breakpoint to be `UIColorBreakForOutOfRangeColorComponents`
[image: set the symbol of the Symbolic Breakpoint]

Step 3: run your app to get the call stack

Follow the call stack of step 3, you will find the key code results in the warning.

Comment: Thank you for this! I learned something new. And this helped me debug my game too.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful with me

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 20):

Short answer: RGB values go from 0-1. You probably entered the straight number. Divide each value by 255.

Long answer: I got this error. I had looked up a color in RGB. This was my code.

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125, green: 125, blue: 125, alpha: 1)`

I used the symbolic breakpoint trick to find which line it was breaking on, but I still didn't know how to fix it.

Then looking at another answer here, I remembered that RGB values have a range of 0-1. The numbers that are given are always [divided by 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486700/why-we-always-divide-rgb-values-by-255).

I changed my code to this:

`view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 125/255, green: 125/255, blue: 125/255, alpha: 1)` and it worked great.

Answer (score 9):

Try this out. It worked fine for me

```
UIColor(red: <Your color>/255.0, green: <Your color>/255.0, blue: <Your color>/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer: RGB values always should be in range like 0-1. You probably entered the straight number and Divide **RGB** color value by 255.

e.g.

```
UIColor(displayP3Red: 41/255.0, green: 128/255.0, blue: 185/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

its working...:)